# Character in string between other strings

Tags: regex

How to find character or a word in string between other strings using regex? for example I want to find `<` character between `<tag>` and `</tag>` tags in string below:

```
"<tag>some text some text < text </tag>"
```

For now I have only found regex which finds whole text between tags:

```
"(?<=<tag>).*(?=<\/tag>)"
```

But how to extract this one character or other word?

Comment: Welcome to SO. As it stands, the question is far too broad. Please add your programming language, the (real) code and your efforts thus far. Otherwise, the question is going to be closed soon.

Comment: Regex isn't a good tool for this, you should use a context-aware parser (probably an XML selection language such as XPath given your sample string). For instance a regex inspired from yours would match the `<` in `<tag></tag> don't match this '<' ! <tag></tag>`.

Comment: It is possible in many flavors supporting `\G`, but the cleanest will be with .NET and PCRE.

Answer (score 0):

One thing that's always a good idea in programming is KISS: Keep It Simple, Stupid.

In this case, I would break your problem into two steps:

1. Get the string between `<tag>..</tag>`.
2. Search for the target in that substring.

By breaking down into smaller problems, you make it much easier for a future programmer (or even Future You) to see what's going on, and make changes to it when requirements change.

Comment: Yes, I realize this is the simplest way but i was wondering if it could be made using regular expressions.

Comment: Why would you want to? There is a simple solution that I have given you, why would you want to make it more complicated just so you can say you used regular expressions?